# Synology DS114 : install getmail with ipkg

Tags: python, nas, synology

I installed getmail with ipkg on my Synology DS114 using those commands:

```
ipkg update
ipkg install python
ipkg install py25-getmail
```

When executing the getmail command, I get this stacktrace:

```
NAS> getmail
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bin/getmail", line 13, in <module>
    import imaplib
  File "/opt/lib/python2.5/imaplib.py", line 25, in <module>
    import binascii, os, random, re, socket, sys, time
  File "/opt/lib/python2.5/random.py", line 58, in <module>
    SG_MAGICCONST = 1.0 + _log(4.5)
OverflowError: math range error
```

Is the getmail package broken? How to fix this please?

Thanks

Comment: is there a reason you arent using the system Python?

Answer (score 3):

**Problem 1:**
The calculation **random.py** is trying to do is over a sudden amount of digits, and that's causing overflow.

> If this seems to take a similarly long period of time to complete, the
>   delay is in finding the fully-qualified hostname of your system. The
>   fix is to ensure you have a valid mapping of address-to-hostname for
>   all the addresses in your system. You can do this in your /etc/hosts
>   file, in your authoritative content DNS server, or in another
>   system-specific manner

try this before executing the "getmail command"

```
python -c "import socket; print socket.getfqdn()"
```

**Problem 2**
*getmail ran out of memory, usually due to a bug in Python's IMAP library which was fixed in early 2008.*

You can most-likely almost fix this by upgrading python to a later version 2.6.x or later. After the upgrade install **getmail** again.
If you're unlucky it could be a secondary error causing this. It's hard to troubleshoot.

Try these solutions, if they don't work,
is there more information you possible could provide?